# Could NOT find Boost (missing: python3) (found version "1.76.0") - CMake Windows

Tags: boost, cmake, windows-10, ros2

I need help solving this cmake boost python3 find problem when trying to compile [cv_bridge](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/tree/ros2/cv_bridge) from ros2, which uses a build tool called [colcon](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/) and in turn CMake. The colcon build error message:

```
> colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install
...    
--- stderr: cv_bridge
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
      Could NOT find Boost (missing: python3) (found version "1.76.0")
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)
```

What I have tried:

- Installing different versions of boost: 1.58, 1.67, 1.76
- Adding to Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS the path to the boost libraries in the CMakeLists.txt of cv_bridge:

```
     if(NOT ANDROID)
          find_package(PythonLibs)
          list(APPEND Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_76_0")
          list(APPEND Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib")
```

- Renaming the `libboost_python38-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib` to `libboost_python38.lib` and `libboost_python3.lib`
- Compiling Boost from source with **bootstrap.bat** and **b2** or installing with the zip file.
- Looked for answers here and elsewhere, which led me to tried things above

I have run out of ideas, please any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try the config version `find_package` to locate boost. Set `Boost_ROOT` before using `find_package`; alternatively add the directory you installed boost to using b2 (`.\b2 ... "--prefix=some/path" ... install`) to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python CONFIG)`. Furthermore note that [the `FindPythonLibs` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPythonLibs.html) is deprecated since cmake 3.12

Comment: Thanks fabian! I tried to set Boost_ROOT, for which the policy CMP0074 needed as well to be set to NEW with no luck. Likewise adding `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` did not work. Also the config version did not work. The config version failed to find `FindPython3Config.cmake` since it does not exist. I found this [thread](https://github.com/boostorg/boost_install/issues/) where it seems that cmake config stops looking where its told to with boost 1.70 and above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it (after a few days of suffering) using [precompiled Boost 1.74](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.74.0/boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe/download) and by changing the boost/python related parts of cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt to:

```
...
set(BOOST_ROOT <your/path/to/boost_1_74_0>)

find_package (Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
if(NOT ANDROID)
    find_package(Boost QUIET)
    if(Boost_VERSION LESS 106500)
        find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
    else()
        # This is a bit of a hack to suppress a warning
        #   No header defined for python3; skipping header check
        # Which should only affect Boost versions < 1.67
        # Resolution for newer versions:
        #  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16391
        if (Boost_VERSION LESS 106700)
            set(_Boost_PYTHON3_HEADERS "boost/python.hpp")
        endif()
        find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python${Python3_VERSION_MAJOR}.${Python3_VERSION_MINOR} REQUIRED)
    endif()
else()
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
endif()
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
...
```

Do not forget to remove build and install folders before triggering colcon build again.

Comment: I almost had given up. Yes, the precompiled Boost really did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar issue while compiling ros noetic on my Fedora. It was able to find `Boost 1.76.0` so I thought the issue should be with the python component. I guess it was not able to find the right `libboost_python` version. So when I checked for the library I found it at this location: `/usr/lib64/libboost_python310.so`.
So I updated the `cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt` to specifically use 3.10 version :

```
if(NOT ANDROID)
  find_package(PythonLibs)

  if(PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "3.8")
    # Debian Buster
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python37)
  else()
    # Ubuntu Focal
    
    # Because I am using python 3.10 I updated
    # this line. If you are using a version less
    # than 3.8, then update the previous line

    # Updated line
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python310)
  endif()
else()
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
endif()
```

Setting it to specifically find the 3.10 version fixed the issue and I was able to compile.

EDIT:
Didn't realize that the question was for Windows Platform but this answer may still help

Comment: That worked perfectly -I also am building ros noetic on fedora. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to give the lib and include folders explicitly to cmake, so as the library itself and I also tried to rename libboost_python37-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib to libboost_python3.lib but non of these worked.

What worked was to simply providing the root to cmake:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\\Boost ..
```

in my case `C:\\Boost` contains the `lib` and `ìnclude` folders that I created using:

```
.\b2 --with-python -j16 --prefix=C:\Boost --libdir=C:\Boost\lib --includedir=C:\Boost\include install
```